# iOS Custom tableview not scrolling

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I am using EWMultipleColumnTableView. In my application it does not scrolling in tableview horizontally nor vertically.

Update:
EWMultiColumnTableView helps to implement MultiColumn table view. As I m using it in my app i need multiple rows and columns which can scroll vertically and horizontally. It works fine when using xib with UIView. Bt it can't scrolls vertically when use it within storyboard and UIViewController. Struggling for it. Help is appreciated.

Comment: You did something wrong. You really should give more details, no one can read your mind...

Comment: Yeah its my bad... I had updated my question.